Getting an overflow error in vba while declaring my data array
I have a problem where i sometimes get an overflow error and sometimes i do not. I have tried changing the range but nothing is working. It is only a small part of my code that does not work which is shown below.
The overflow mistake occurs when decalring the data array.
`
'Load FEES
Dim arrayetab() As Variant
Dim ilastrow3 As Long
Dim data() As Variant
Dim ilastRow As Long


ilastRow = shR.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
data = shR.Range("A2:Z" & CStr(ilastRow)).Value


ilastrow3 = shF.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
arrayetab = shF.Range("A14:M" & CStr(ilastrow3)).Value

For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)

    For y = LBound(arrayetab) To UBound(arrayetab)
    
        If Split(data(i, 3), ".")(0) = arrayetab(y, 4) Then
        
            If CDbl(data(i, 22)) <= 5000 And arrayetab(y, 1) = "30000" Then
        
                GoTo per
                
            Else
            
                data(i, 24) = arrayetab(y, 11)
                data(i, 25) = arrayetab(y, 10)
                
            End If
            
            
        End If
        
per:
    Next y
    

Next i

Tried redeclaring the range but it still does not work.
I dont think its related to the size of the array since it is only 115 lines this times and sometimes i run it for a couple of 100 lines.

Try declaring Dim arrayetab, data, I mean, not declaring them as arrays. Then, using CStr(ilastRow) is useless. ilastRow is enough. Now, what do you understand by "while declaring my data array"? Where the error is raised? On the declaration line? I have some doubts... If not, isn't it a specific code line yellow highlighted when press Continue? If yes, which code line?

How large is your data - how many rows do you have? You haven't declares i, so it's created on the fly when you use it and the VBA runtime assumes it's an Integer. If you have more that 32k row, you will get an overflow for that.
